# user post upload buddypress

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I am using `buddypress` for my website. I am searching for a plugin which allows members to `post articles, stories and poems`. It is good if the member can upload documents with it. I have searched a lot but couldn't find suitable one which works with buddypress. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Front-end Editor by Scribu:

http://wordpress.org/plugins/front-end-editor/

You could set up custom post types for articles, stories and poems:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types